# For what values of x, would tan x lie in the range from (-1,1)?

Tags: trigonometry

Please tell me a method to find this. And how do I check the range for tan function if I am given a random interval for the angle.

Comment: There are infinite, disjoint intervals that fulfill the condition. Do you want this or some limited interval?

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**:

$$-1<\tan x<1\iff -\frac\pi4+k\pi<x<\frac\pi4+k\pi\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z$$

Try to make sense of the above...

Answer (score 0):

$$tan(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)} \quad \forall x \in \mathbb R \setminus\{\pi/2+k\pi, k\in \mathbb Z\}$$

$$-1<\tan x<1\iff \lvert\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}\rvert < 1 \iff \lvert \sin(x) \rvert < \lvert \cos(x) \rvert  $$

Looking at the trigonometric circle then gives you the rest... i.e.

$$\lvert \sin(x) \rvert < \lvert \cos(x) \rvert  \iff -\pi/4+k\pi<x<\pi/4+k\pi \quad \forall k \in \mathbb Z$$

As for your second question, given an interval $[x1,x2]$

$$ \exists k \in \mathbb Z \quad \vert \quad x1 < \pi/2+k\pi < x2 \implies range = ]-\infty,+\infty[$$
$$\not \exists k \in \mathbb Z \quad \vert \quad x1 < \pi/2+k\pi < x2 \implies range = [\arctan(x1),\arctan(x2)]$$